# IntentService and Handler+Looper

Tags: android, intentservice

Does IntentService is a Handler+Looper implementation?

Only difference being that IntentService is triggered by Intents

IntentService http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Handler +Looper http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Answer (score 3):

Looper is an abstraction over event loop (infinite loop which drains queue with events) and Handler is an abstraction to put/remove events into/from queue with events (which is drained by Looper) and handle these events when they are processed.[image: Handler and Looper]

Looper is a class that runs message loop for some thread. In Java we have threads, in which we might do some useful work. Initially threads don’t have an event loop capabilities, but we can add this capabilities via attaching Looper to them.

Looper has two main methods: prepare and loop. The first method prepare — inits thread and attaches Looper to it. The second method loop starts event loop.

Handler is a class which allows you to send and handle Messages and Runnables from thread’s MessageQueue.
Basically it works the following way:
Client initializes Handler and Looper (so the whole infrastructure is now ready to use)
Client sends messages to Handler
Handler posts messages to Looper’s MessageQueue
Looper processes messages in MessageQueue
When message is ready to be processed, Looper sends it back to Handler, which can handle message.
So, we see that Handler does two things: 1) posts messages to be placed in a queue, 2) handles messages when they were processed by Looper.

Reference
https://proandroiddev.com/decoding-handler-and-looper-in-android-d4f3f2449513

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [IntentService source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java), it does indeed use a Handler+Looper for its internal logic.